# Are there situations where cyclic references are absolutely necessary?

Tags: garbage-collection, programming-languages

I'm designing a programming language and I intend for it to support multiple garbage collection strategies including ordinary reference counting. In fact, ordinary reference counting should be the default. The language supports both owning and unowning references.

I'm considering whether the language should completely not support cyclic ownership, that is, when there's a path of owning references from an object back to itself, or whether to allow it as an option in which case the compiler chooses a garbage collection strategy that can handle reference cycles. I'm more partial to the former because cyclic ownership doesn't seem to make much sense to me. It doesn't seem natural. In the real world, everything is contained in some other thing; you can't contain yourself. I mean, in what situation might an object need to own itself? For reference, closures which capture themselves or the object that contain them capture the object using an unowning reference.

To be clear, I am aware that allowing cyclic owning references would certainly make solving some problems easier. However, many problems can be redesigned in such a way that ownership cycles are broken. For e.g., in a doubly-linked list, the "head" and "next" references could be made owning, while the "tail" and "previous" references could be made unowning. My question is, are there problems that cannot be refactored to break cycles? If so, please give an example.

Assume that we have access to the following type of references:

1. Unique owning reference - This reference has unique ownership of an object. Once this reference goes out of scope, the object can be dropped. This reference cannot be cloned.
2. Shared owning reference - This reference has joint ownership of an object. The object must only be dropped when all references have gone out of scope.
3. Unowning reference - This reference does not have ownership of an object. It can only exist as long the object has an owning reference with lifetime greater or equal to this reference.
4. Weak reference to a shared object - This also doesn't own the object, but the reference is allowed to outlive all the owning references to this object. This reference can tell us whether the object is still alive or not.

Comment: See [What are the practical examples of reference cycles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51458072/2711488) Your question seems to be biased to a solution that is searching for a fitting problem. Reference counting might be simple to implement but is the worst memory management strategy.

Comment: @Holger I do know that in terms of throughput reference counting is not the best, which is why there are others. However, the benefits it provide such as no pause-times to run the gc might be more beneficial to many applications than overall throughput performance.

Comment: First of all, you have to ask yourself how you deal with “unowning references” when all “owning references” have been removed. Either, you leave them invalid, which gives you all disadvantages of manual memory management, or you clear them, which requires a traversal, which gives the disadvantages of a traversing gc you wanted to avoid. And in every nontrivial scenario, the counting system is as unpredictable as any gc, because every removal of a reference could be the last reference to the root of a large object graph that must be traversed and freed immediately, yielding large pause times.

Comment: In other words, you get the worst of all worlds, without any benefit.

Comment: @Holger In the language, "unowning references" are actually untracked. This is why they're not allowed to outlive the "owning reference" they were obtained from. So an unowning reference to an object cannot exist while there are no longer any owning references to it. With regards to deleting the root of a large object graph, yes I see that we might get pause times from that. I personally know that reference counting is not the best garbage-collection mechanism, but I want to support it anyway for those who want it. That's why I want to know if it's okay to sacrifice cyclic owning references.

Comment: Does “they're not allowed to” imply that you found a way to enforce this or that it is precisely the first scenario I already described (“*you leave them invalid, which gives you all disadvantages of manual memory management*”)?

Comment: @Holger Oh the compiler enforces this. We make use of lifetimes, similar to what you have in Rust. In addition to the named lifetime in Rust, I added a new one, 'self, to represent when an unowning reference references the object that contains/owns it. This and a couple of other features would allow you to implement a cyclic data-structure like a linked list without writing unsafe code.

Comment: If that works, you probably covered all relevant use cases.

Comment: @Holger Yeah I think so too, but I can't be 100% sure. My plan is to not allow cyclic ownership on the initial release of the language. Then if a programmer comes across a situation where they couldn't solve their problem without it, they could raise an issue, we would examine and if it proves correct, we can now release a version of the language that supports it.

Comment: I seem to remember hearing about a persisted (/immutable) datastructure that strictly requires a GC, but this could have been a decade ago, I don't remember its name.